# Python Seperate thread for list which automatically removes after time limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I want to have a list which my main process will add data to and this seperate thread will see the data added, wait a set amount of eg 1 minute then remove it from the list. Im not very experience with multi-threading in python so i dont know how to do this.

Comment: this seems like a design flaw, what are you trying to achieve. it kind of sounds like you are trying to describe a queue

Answer (score 0):

The way you could achieve this is by using a global variable as your list, as your thread will be able to access data from it. You can use a deque from the collections library, and each time you add something in the queue, you spawn a new thread that will just pop from the front after waiting that set amount of time.

Although, you have to be careful with the race conditions. It may happen that you try to write something at one end in your main thread and at the same time erase something from the beginning in one of your new threads, and this will cause unexpected behavior.

Best way to avoid this is by using a lock.